# bootstrap styles are not being applied to print in react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a POS invoice module. It works in the print. i mean when i click on the print button it shows the dialog box but it doesn't come up with boostrap styles.

I tried using and importing the css of the boootstrap in the top of the code but it still did not work.

I tried using online css url and the link but it still did not work.

[image]

```
 const handlePrint = () => {
    const printableArea = document.getElementById('printable-area');

    const clonedContent = printableArea.cloneNode(true);

    const printFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
    printFrame.style.display = 'none';

    document.body.appendChild(printFrame);

    printFrame.onload = () => {
     
      const printDocument = printFrame.contentDocument || printFrame.contentWindow.document;
      printDocument.body.appendChild(clonedContent);

      printFrame.contentWindow.print();

    };

    printFrame.src = 'about:blank';
  };
```

```
<div className="pt-0 pb-3 modal-body" id="printable-area" style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}>
            <div className="mt-4 mb-4 text-black text-center fs-1">POS</div>
            <table className="table">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td className="p-0">
                    <span>Date:</span>
                    <span className="ms-2 font-label"> {masterDetails.master_bill_date}</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td className="p-0">
                    <span className="address__label d-inline-block">Address:</span>
                    <span className="ms-2 address__value d-inline-block font-label"> {customerDetails.customer_billing_address}</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td className="p-0">
                    <span>Email:</span>
                    <span className="ms-2 font-label"> {customerDetails.customer_email}</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td className="p-0">
                    <span>Phone:</span>
                    <span className="ms-2 font-label"> {customerDetails.customer_mobile}</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td className="p-0">
                    <span>Customer : </span>
                    <span className="ms-2 font-label"> {customerDetails.customer_name}</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            {productsList.map((product, index) =>
            (
              <div key={index} style={{ borderBottom: "2px solid black" }}>
                <div className="p-0" style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>
                  {product.product_english_name.toLowerCase()} <span></span>
                </div>
                <div className="product-border">
                  <div className="border-0 d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <span className="">{product.pos_qty} X {product.pos_salePrice * product.pos_qty}</span>
                    <span className="text-end">&#8377; {product.pos_totalPrice}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            )
            )}
            <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
              <div className="product-border">
                <div><b>T. Amt :</b> &#8377; {masterDetails.master_total_bill_amt}</div>
                <div className="text-end ms-auto"></div>
              </div>
              <div className="product-border">
                <div><b>Dis :</b> &#8377; 0.00</div>
                <div className="text-end ms-auto"></div>
              </div>
              <div className="product-border">
                <div><b>G. Total :</b> &#8377; {masterDetails.master_total_bill_amt}</div>
                <div className="text-end ms-auto"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            {/* <table className="mb-0 table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th className="py-2 px-0">Paid By</th>
                  <th className="text-end py-2 px-0">Amount</th>
                  <th className="text-end py-2 px-0">Change Return</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td className="py-2 px-0">Cash</td>
                  <td className="text-end py-2 px-0">&#8377;  {masterDetails.master_total_bill_amt}</td>
                  <td className="text-end py-2 px-0">&#8377; 0.00</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table> */}
            <h5 className="text-center font-label">Thank You For Shopping With Us. Please visit again.</h5>
            {/* <div className="text-center d-block">
              <img src="https://infypos-demo.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/sales/barcode-SA_11121489.png" height="25" width="100" className="" />
              <span className="d-block">SA_11121489</span>
            </div> */}
          </div>
```